# Redis Cluster Mode: Not announcing the static IP

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis, redis-cluster

So, we have a Redis cluster mode enabled up and running in an EC2 instance(can't use the AWS managed one) and to connect to it from our internal network we are announcing our IP and Port using `cluster-announce-ip,cluster-announce-port and cluster-bus-port` where the IP announced is accessible from our network.
It seems to be working fine but not stable i.e. it keeps on switching between the IP provided and the loopback address, see below:

```
internal:36379> cluster nodes
eec09ffe56b05ad12b615b1d72fb6759f9c442dd internal:36379@40002 slave,fail b48e9381bfc8870317890483f3a610195a88c726 1580294719147 1580294718345 8 connected
ca0cb878becba2270cf00ec75be806304d561b0b internal:36379@40003 slave 3a5c9bc26bb3fbc7e850199320595946f3a6569a 1580294720250 1580294719347 9 connected
3a5c9bc26bb3fbc7e850199320595946f3a6569a internal:30006@40006 myself,master - 0 1580294720000 9 connected 10923-16383
33de5143f47674dd0fc636404fe4d7752d2cf9e2 internal:36379@40004 master - 1580294720651 1580294720151 7 connected 0-5460
b48e9381bfc8870317890483f3a610195a88c726 internal:36379@40005 master,fail - 1580294721253 1580294721153 8 connected 5461-10922
74cd3e1ededd204408e2dabce022bd08ab6b03b3 internal:36379@40001 slave,fail 33de5143f47674dd0fc636404fe4d7752d2cf9e2 1580215532177 1580215531374 7 connected
internal:36379> 
internal:36379> cluster nodes
eec09ffe56b05ad12b615b1d72fb6759f9c442dd 127.0.0.1:30002@40002 slave b48e9381bfc8870317890483f3a610195a88c726 0 1580294727000 8 connected
ca0cb878becba2270cf00ec75be806304d561b0b 127.0.0.1:30003@40003 slave 3a5c9bc26bb3fbc7e850199320595946f3a6569a 0 1580294727381 9 connected
3a5c9bc26bb3fbc7e850199320595946f3a6569a internal:30006@40006 myself,master - 0 1580294726000 9 connected 10923-16383
33de5143f47674dd0fc636404fe4d7752d2cf9e2 internal:36379@40004 master,fail? - 1580294725274 1580294725000 7 connected 0-5460
b48e9381bfc8870317890483f3a610195a88c726 127.0.0.1:30005@40005 master,fail - 0 1580294727080 8 connected 5461-10922
74cd3e1ededd204408e2dabce022bd08ab6b03b3 internal:36379@40001 slave,fail 33de5143f47674dd0fc636404fe4d7752d2cf9e2 1580215532177 1580215531374 7 connected
internal:36379>
```

Where `internal` is one of our six internal IPs.Originally cluster is running on `ports 30001-30006`.We are able to set/get keys momentarily before it switches back to announcing the local address instead of our IP.
Any idea why this is not stable?